# Error on deploy

Tags: google-cloud-datalab

I keep getting this error when i try to deploy. Billing is enabled and so is the compute engine api so i cant really see what else could be going on.

Has anyone else come across this?

> The request to deploy Google Cloud Datalab for boreal-antonym-XXX
>   failed. Please make sure that the project is enabled for billing.
>   Additionally, you must be an owner or editor within the project.
>   Occasionally, a deployment request may fail due to transient errors or
>   insufficient capacity. If so, please try again.

Comment: I've also changed billing accounts to one that is linked to a project where datalab works and still got this error so its not the case of an incorrect billing account like the error suggests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to look in the deployment logs to see what is going wrong.

Those logs are copied to a GCS bucket in the same project named '${project}-datalab'.

First, use `gsutil ls` to find the matching logs:

```
LOGS_FILE=`gsutil ls gs://boreal-antonym-XXX-datalab/logs | sort | tail -n 1`
```

The file will be something along the lines of `main-20160701-00-00-00.txt`

Then, use `gsutil cat` to list the contents of those logs:

```
gsutil cat ${LOGS_FILE}
```

Finally, look through that output to see what error messages are shown.

Comment: Thanks - i don't think it's even getting as far as writing to logs for some reason. I'm getting "BucketNotFoundException: 404 gs://boreal-antonym-128915-datalab bucket does not exist." Error when trying to find the log file.

Comment: See if you can manually create a GCE VM in the project. If that doesn't work, then fix whatever issue is blocking that first, and then try again.